# Django throwing error django.db.utils.IntegrityError: UNIQUE constraint failed: mediaSort_userdata.user_id

Tags: python, django

I'm testing my models on my django app and whenever i try to save my extended User model (using a OneToOne relationship) it throws that error

**models.py**

```
class UserData(models.Model):
    lastSeason = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    lastChapter = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    user = models.OneToOneField(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

**This is what i do on the manage.py shell:**

```
>>> from django.contrib.auth.models import User
>>> from mediaSort.models import Show, UserData
>>> import datetime
>>> usL = User.objects.get(username='luciano')
>>> newUs = UserData(lastSeason=1,lastChapter=2,user=usL)
>>> newUs.save()
```

**And this is the error:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Luciano\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 85, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\Luciano\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py", line 303, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
sqlite3.IntegrityError: UNIQUE constraint failed: mediaSort_userdata.user_id

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Luciano\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 729, in save
    force_update=force_update, update_fields=update_fields)
  File "C:\Users\Luciano\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 759, in save_base
    updated = self._save_table(raw, cls, force_insert, force_update, using, update_fields)
  File "C:\Users\Luciano\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 842, in _save_table
    result = self._do_insert(cls._base_manager, using, fields, update_pk, raw)
  File "C:\Users\Luciano\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 880, in _do_insert
    using=using, raw=raw)
  File "C:\Users\Luciano\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py", line 82, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Luciano\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 1125, in _insert
    return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(return_id)
  File "C:\Users\Luciano\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 1280, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\Luciano\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 100, in execute
    return super().execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\Luciano\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 68, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
  File "C:\Users\Luciano\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 77, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "C:\Users\Luciano\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 85, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\Luciano\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 89, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "C:\Users\Luciano\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 85, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\Luciano\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py", line 303, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: UNIQUE constraint failed: mediaSort_userdata.user_id
```

Am I missing something here? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you already have a UserData object with the user Luciano , try checking if thats the case. It will be helpful if can post what all entries you have in your db for User and UserData table.

Comment: That was it! I feel so dumb. Thank you so much

Comment: Ok, i have another problem now... if i try to save another user data but for the same user it throws this error. Is there any way of doing it?

Comment: @LucianoSaputo Can you elaborate it a bit more ?

Comment: Thank you for answering! I was trying to save multiple instances of user data for the same user in this case 'luciano' it didnt work because the relationship between them is OneToOne, i realized of this so i changed to Foreign Key and it worked!